# JSON - jquery to php; how to POST data

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I have a JSON object (`postData`) I want to send to my PHP web service.

```
$.ajax({
    url: postLink,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    complete: function () {
        console.log('COMPLETE: tried to send json');
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Success" + data);
        if (data.success) {
             // do something
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log("ERROR" + error);
    }
});
```

In PHP (Symfony) I read it as such:

```
$content = htmlspecialchars_decode($this->get('request')->getContent(), ENT_NOQUOTES);
$data = array();

if (!empty($content))
{
    $data = json_decode($content, true);

    var_dump($content);
```

I'm getting an INTERNAL SERVER ERROR on the `json_decode`. I believe it's because (according to my `var_dump`) the JSON is coming through to the webservice looks like this:

```
&quot;auth&quot;:{&quot;username&quot;:&quot; ...
```

I even tried adding `htmlspecialchars_decode` to convert those quotations back to `"'... but it still comes back as`"`

I've got no idea what to do. So any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` creates a HTML printable string. Where is your post data coming from? Try using `serialize` or `serializeArray` on your form.

Comment: can you log your : JSON.stringify(postData). If you send a json object, php will understand it like an array (if it s an js object )

Answer (score 0):

Remove `htmlspecialchars_decode`

Use:

```
$content = html_entity_decode($this->get('request')->getContent());
$data = json_decode($content);
```

All the problem is because of `JSON.stringify(postData)`. Do you really need this?

Comment: He mentioned in the question that he "tried" the `htmlspecialchars_decode`. This should have been a comment.